# How to Add moon phases on calendar

Tags: iphone, calendar

how to add moon phases on google calendar?. Is there any calculation to add moon phases based on the date.

Comment: You've put a lot of links to random pieces of code in your question, but none of it appears to be related to this task.

Comment: @duskwuff my mistack see my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

You can add calendars using these instructions (Phases of the moon is listed under 'More'):
http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37098

Then simply sync it to your iPhone as you would any other calendar.

Comment: please send another code that link does not work in my code.

Comment: Perhaps I miss understood your questions, but here is a link to the [Google moon phases calendar in .ics](http://www.google.com/calendar/ical/ht3jlfaac5lfd6263ulfh4tql8%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics)

If this calendar doesn't work you should elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i found solution of my answer. i create custom own calendar and add moon in one by one date moon with the use of php side logic . but thanks for your support.